# Crystal Report Sub report Shared Variable is not returning to concern Group section

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Report

Sub report Shared Variable is not returning to concern Group section as Shown Below with simple example.
After making Shared variable in both main and sub, values of subrepo need to return in corresponding main report field. but instead it returns on next group section as shown below

### Group1

```
  SharedVAR Sales Happen=
```

Group 2
         Sub Report
    date                    sales
    1-jan-2012        123.44    SharedVAR Sales happen=Y

### Group1

```
  SharedVAR Sales Happen=Y
```

Group 2
         Sub Report
    date            sales
    --  No records

Please suggest Thank you in advance.
SHB

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that shared variables are always evaluated while printing, and the Group1 header is printed before Group2.  If you move the totals to display in the Group1 footer instead of the Group1 header, it should work fine.

Depending on the report, you also may be able to combine them together: either move the sub-report data into the main report (and get rid of the sub-report), or suppress the group1 header in the main report and show that data in the report header section of the sub-report.